# How to change inner content of moving div

Tags: jquery

When I click on "Login" button only "Form1" should be visible and "Form2" hidden, and when click on "Signup" button "Form2" visible and "Form1" hidden, how to do?

HTML :

```
<div class="box">
  <div class="first">
    Login Form
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    Signup Form
  </div>
</div>

<button type="button" id="btn-login">Login</button>
<button type="button" id="btn-signup">Signup</button>
```

CSS:

```
div.box {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    padding:10px;
    background: red;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transition: transform 2s ease; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: transform 2s ease;
}

.move-right {
    -ms-transform: translateX(400px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(400px); /* Safari */
    transform: translateX(400px);
}
.move-left {
    -ms-transform: translateX(0px); /* IE 9 */
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px); /* Safari */
    transform: translateX(0px);
}
```

jQuery:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btn-login").click(function(){
        $("div.box").removeClass("move-right");
        $("div.box").addClass("move-left");
      });

      $("#btn-signup").click(function(){
        $("div.box").removeClass("move-left");
        $("div.box").addClass("move-right");
      });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use css property display

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $("#btn-login").click(function(){
        $(".second").css("display", "none");
        $(".first").css("display", "block");
        $("div.box").removeClass("move-right");
        $("div.box").addClass("move-left");
      });

      $("#btn-signup").click(function(){
      $(".second").css("display", "block");
        $(".first").css("display", "none");
        $("div.box").removeClass("move-left");
        $("div.box").addClass("move-right");
      });
    });
```

i've made changes check out at this link https://jsfiddle.net/eg8Lf86d/

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#btn-login").click(function(){
     $("div.box").removeClass("move-right");
     $("div.box").addClass("move-left");
     $('.second').addClass('hidden');
     $('.first').removeClass('hidden');
   });

   $("#btn-signup").click(function(){
     $("div.box").removeClass("move-left");
     $("div.box").addClass("move-right");
     $('.first').addClass('hidden');
     $('.second').removeClass('hidden');
   });
});
```

In your css:

```
.hidden{
  display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks friends for quick response, I set this code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.second').addClass('hidden');

   $("#btn-login").click(function(){
     $("div.box").removeClass("move-right");
     $("div.box").addClass("move-left");
     $('.second').addClass('hidden');
     $('.first').removeClass('hidden');
   });

   $("#btn-signup").click(function(){
     $("div.box").removeClass("move-left");
     $("div.box").addClass("move-right");
     $('.first').addClass('hidden');
     $('.second').removeClass('hidden');
   });
});
```